# Cambiar color de imageView Programáticamente

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

Tengo un imageView, su propiedad SRC es un vector, al cual desde xml puedo cambiar su color con lo siguiente .

```
app:tint="#CF5858"
```

**Imagen**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ctr_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ctr_btn_pl_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:tint="#CF5858" />
```

Como puedo realiza el cambio desde código Kotlin.

No hay una propiedad TINT que pueda usar, he visto que en algunos ejemplos usan ColorStateList, sin embargo se me esta complicando su uso, ya que hay muchos ejemplos con código que no me funciona por que esta deprecado o implementaciones demasiado complejas a mi parecer, para solo poder cambiar el color.

**ACTUALIZACION**
Esto funciona

```
ctr_btn.setColorFilter(R.color.purple_500)
```

Sin embargo quisiera comprobar si la imagen(vector) ya tiene ese mismo color, para cambiar a su color por defecto, Pero con lo anterior no puedo hacerlo.

```
ctr_btn.setOnClickListener {
            if(ctr_btn.setColorFilter == R.color.purple_500){   //NO SE PUEDE
                ctr_btn.setColorFilter(R.color.original)
            }else{
                ctr_btn.setColorFilter(R.color.purple_500)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para estos casos donde tienes que alternar entre dos estados es recomendable usar un `CheckBox` y crear el `ColorStateList` en xml.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ctr_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/ic_home"
    app:buttonTint="@color/icon_tint" // archivo xml que contiene el ColorStateList
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ctr_btn_pl_next"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

El `ColorStateList` debes crearlo en la carpeta `res/color/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/original" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/purple_500" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

Si lo haces de esta manera no necesitas escribir ningún código en el `setOnClickListener`. El ícono cambiará de color automaticamente cada vez que lo presiones.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, para obtener el color de un `ImageView` programáticamente puedes usar `ctr_btn.imageTintList.defaultColor` y para cambiarlo `ctr_btn.imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.purple_500)`.
Si tu app soporta dispositivos con un API level menor a 21, en cambio debes usar `ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList()` y `ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList()`

**PD**: por favor nombra bien las cosas a menos que quieras ser el único capaz de entender tu código. Cualquiera que vea algo llamado "ctr_btn" va a creer que es un `Button` y un color nunca puede llamarse "original" ¿qué color se supone que es ese?